# Can I run code online after I write it on Github?

Tags: git, build, compilation

Can I write code, build apps and run everything with Flutter(Dart) on GitHub or Bamboo or any other git tool? Or it's only doable on the computer?

Thnx

Comment: AFAIK you can not run anything on github. Unless you're talking about github actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### VCS

git is only a **V**ersion **C**ontrol **S**ystem, which simply said will help you to manage your code, and help you to track what you did when and why you did it. It has nothing to do with building or running code in the first place.
Git can save your code in local and remote repositories. But you will always have a local repository on your computer if you work with code, that is versioned by git. You can read more about Version Control Systems [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).

### Remote repositories

GitHub and Bitbucket are platforms, which provide a storage for remote repositories which you can synchronize your changes too, so that you can work with different people in different locations and also have a remote backup of your code in case something happens to your local computer. You will however always changes your code on your own computer in your development environment until you decide to publish your code to a remote repository and share it with the world.

### Building and running remote code

It is possible to build, test and deploy code via Github by using Github Actions. But you always should test your app localy before publishing your code to a remote repository

Comment: *replace bamboo with bitbucket. Bamboo is a  continuous integration and deployment tool (made by Atlassian).

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know :)

Comment: That's ok. You now know!

Comment: Thanks so much for this valuable information, but how will I be able tol share my app with the world? in other words: will online repository help me with that?@andymeissner